# Functional programming for 3 lists in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I could manage following code to replaces items in a list using 2 other lists. Orilist and newlist have original and new terms in order. The replacement is done using orilist and newlist- if orilist items are present in slist, slist is changed to have corresponding new items from newlist:

```
(define (list-replace-from-lists slist orilist newlist)
  (define replaced #f)
  (define outl '())
  (for ((item slist))
    (set! replaced #f)
    (for ((ori_ orilist) (i (in-naturals))  #:when (equal? item ori_))
      (set! outl (cons (list-ref newlist i) outl))
      (set! replaced #t))
    (when (not replaced)
      (set! outl (cons item outl))))
  (reverse outl))
```

To replace 2 and 5 to 12 and 15, respectively, in (list 1 2 3 4 5 6) :

```
(list-replace-from-lists (list 1 2 3 4 5 6) (list 2 5) (list 12 15))
```

Output is:

```
'(1 12 3 4 15 6)
```

However, above code does not look functional and has many set! statements. How can this be converted to functional code? Should I use structures or some other data-types for above purpose?

Edit: items may recur in original list, e.g. `(list 1 2 3 4 5 2 6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use lists and keep everything functional. :-) Here's my solution:

```
(define (replace-all haystack needles new-needles)
  (define replace-alist (map cons needles new-needles))
  (define (replace-one item)
    (cond ((assoc item replace-alist) => cdr)
          (else item)))
  (map replace-one haystack))
```

Explanation of the code:

1. First, we build a replacement *association list* (alist). This is a list of pairs, of which the keys correspond to the `needles` and the values correspond to `new-needles`.
2. Then we define a `replace-one` function that takes an item, and sees if it matches any of the keys in the alist. If so, we return the corresponding value; otherwise, we return the original item.
3. Finally, we map the `haystack` through `replace-one`. Yay higher-order functions!

Note that this code is `O(m*n)` where `m` is the size of `haystack` and `n` is the size of `needles`, which is the same runtime as your version. If `needles` is large, you will want to use a hashtable instead of an alist, which will amortise the runtime of the function to `O(m)`.

Comment: Your solution does not work if an item occurs again later in haystack, e.g. (replace (list 1 2 3 4 5 2 6) (list 2 5) (list 12 15)) . The second 2 is not replaced.

Comment: I posted a simple example and your solution is really elegant for that. But recurring items are not ruled out.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for solution as well as clear explanation. It will be great for all readers if you could also put the hashtable version here for clarity.

Comment: Can you explain  the use of => here. It seems to be  an  uncommonly used symbol.

Comment: @rnso Sylwester already posted a hash version, so I won't bother to do so. ;-) As regard the `=>`, it's a `cond` syntax that stores the test value, and if truthy, passes it to the given function. In this case, it's equivalent to: `(let ((value (assoc item replace-alist))) (if value (cdr value) ...))` where the `...` represents the failure case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional solution that uses hash to keep the associations. That makes this solution O(haystack-length log needle-length) since immutable hashes are implemented with trees.

```
(define (list-replace-all haystack needles new-values)
  ;; make a dictionary of elements to be replaced
  (define hash
    (foldl (λ (needle new-value hash)
             (hash-set hash needle new-value))
           #hash()
           needles
           new-values))
  ;; do the replace. If not in hash the actual key is default
  (map (λ (e) (hash-ref hash e e)) haystack))

(list-replace-all '(1 2 3 4 5 6) '(2 5) '(12 15))
; ==> (1 12 3 4 15 6)
```

Comment: Prefer to use `for/hash` for this (`(for/hash ((needle (in-list needles)) (new-value (in-list new-values))) (values needle new-value))`). Otherwise, excellent answer. +1

Comment: I am glad my question produced educative answers. I do not know why this question was downvoted.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yes, it looks clearer. Why do you use `in-list`? Both are already a list and every element will be touched. @mso Probably since it works. it's more of a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: @Sylwester It's a micro-optimisation. Without specifying the generator, the system has to look at the object's type at runtime to decide on the generator to use.

Comment: I timed (for ((item mylist))..  vs (for ((item (in-list mylist))).. . In-list (the second version) is much faster. Similarly (for ((i (in-range n))) was much faster than (for ((i n)) or (for ((i (range n))).